# get the data from SQL and put in jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp, autocompletebox

I'm trying to do the autocomplete textbox  at jsp. But i have no idea how to include all the data that retrieved from database to use to match the value that user key in. Please help, thanks a lot.

```
  <%
    String FRUIT= "";

    TEST.makeConnection();
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM TB_FRUIT WITH UR";
    TEST.executeQuery(SQL);     
    while(TEST.getNextQuery())
    {
        FRUIT= TEST.getColumnString("FRUIT_DESCP");
    }   
    TEST.takeDown();    
   %>

  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
   <script>
    $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      //how can i include the data(FRUIT) from database to put in here? 

      "Apple", // i hardcode this to do testing for my current autocomplete textbox
      "Avocado", // i hardcode this to do testing for my current autocomplete textbox
      "Banana",// i hardcode this to do testing for my current autocomplete textbox
      "Durian",// i hardcode this to do testing for my current autocomplete textbox
      "Mango",// i hardcode this to do testing for my current autocomplete textbox
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
      });
    });
  </script>      
  <body>
       <div class="ui-widget">
         <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
         <input id="tags">
       </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a JSP expert, but I think I can spot a couple of issues in your code:

1. `FRUIT` will always have the value of the last record from your query because you are not concatenating the values but replacing the value with the new one.

   You want `FRUIT` to be a list of strings like this: `"fruit1","fruit2","fruit3",...`, to do that, you should be doing something like this:

   ```
   FRUIT += "\"" + TEST.getColumnString("FRUIT_DESCP") + "\",";
   ```
2. Even if you got the value correctly, you are not displaying it on the website. Now that you have the value of `FRUIT` in a format that autocomplete will understand, you just need to print it:

   ```
   var availableTags = [
       <% out.print(FRUIT); %>
   ];
   ```

And that should do the trick.

In the end, the code would look like this:

```
<%
    String FRUIT= "";

    TEST.makeConnection();
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM TB_FRUIT WITH UR";
    TEST.executeQuery(SQL);     
    while(TEST.getNextQuery())
    {
        FRUIT += "\"" + TEST.getColumnString("FRUIT_DESCP") + "\",";
    }   
    TEST.takeDown();    
   %>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
   <script>
    $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        <% out.print(FRUIT); %>
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
      });
    });
  </script>      
  <body>
       <div class="ui-widget">
         <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
         <input id="tags">
       </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The variable FRUIT will have an unnecessary comma at the end that you should remove. You could do it like this: `FRUIT = FRUIT.substring(0, FRUIT.length()-1);`

Comment: Thanks you @Alvaro Montoro

Comment: Hi @Alvaro Montoro may i know how can i solve for the following issue ? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693009/throw-sql-value-to-jquery-availabletag

Comment: The question was removed